# Как изменить текст кнопки?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Появилась задача поменять кнопку в гугл форме, со стандартного "Submit" на что-то другое.

Возможно ли это в принципе с помощью языка Google app Script?
И если да, помогите написать код.

Comment: На сколько мне известно, данную кнопку поменять нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script является таким же приложением экосистемы Гугл, как и остальные. Гугл не создает на нем свои программы и никак не расширяет их за счет скриптов. Существуют сервисы, которые могут взаимодействовать с пользователем через определенные инструменты скриптов, но они, обычно, ограничиваются визуализацией данных и отправкой/приемом данных между клиентом и сервером.

Скрипты не могут повлиять на внешний вид Форм, кроме тех случаев, которые описаны в API.